# Installing VoteFu on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The instructions of vote-fu say to use ./script/generate, but I believe that is deprecated for Rails 3. I tried to use 'rails generate vote_fu Article', but it says 'Could not find generator vote_fu'. I installed it by adding it to Gemfile and running 'bundle install'.
How do I install this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the new, Rails3 updated version:
https://github.com/vshvedov/vote_fu_rails_3

Now dance! :)